# Second order difference plot

Tags: matlab

I am working on a project in which I need to compute the second order difference plot of a data series. The data vector is x(n) and I need to compute following values to plot on a graph:

```
X(n) = x(n+1)- x(n)-----Equation(1)
Y(n) = x(n+2) - x(n-1)-------Equation(2)
```

Then the plot of X(n) vs. Y(n) will be my SODP.
How to compute x(n+1) for first equation and x(n+2) for the second equation in MATLAB. I tried the following code to compute the values of x(n+1):

```
X = zeros(1,N);
% Assume the first element is A1
X(1) = A1;
for n = 1:(N-1)
if rem(n,2) == 0
% even case
An = A0;
else
% odd case
An = A1;
end
% step to increment X(n) to X(n+1)
X(n+1) = An*X(n)
end
```

But I am getting the same x(n) data as output.
I appreciate any input on the question.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What do your array x and y look like? From your algorithm, it seems your x is `[A1, A1*A1, A0*A1^2, A0*A1^3 ...]`. Is this correct?

Comment: Dear Anthony, 
'x'  is a TXT-file consists of 4096 samples of one EEG time series in ASCII code. I am reading this file as x(n) and need to compute x(n+1) and x(n+2). Hope this gives you a clear  idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=rand(1E4,1); %example vector
X=x(2:end)-x(1:end-1); %x(n+1)-x(n)
Y=[nan;x(3:end)-x(1:end-2)]; %x(n+2)-x(n-1)
plot(X,Y,'.')
```

Y is calculated like this:

Y(1) = nan (cannot compute x(1-1), x(0) does not exist)

Y(2) = x(3)-x(1)

Y(3) = x(4)-x(2)

etc.

Comment: Dear Gelliant, thank you for the answer. In signals and systems perspective, the signal x(n) is shifted on time scale to get x(n+1). I could not get why you have taken 'NaN' in Y=[nan;x(3:end)-x(1:end-2)]; Any suggestion Please suggest, can shifting the signal give me the required results?

Comment: Dear Dattaprasad, I made it nan because I cannot compute x(1-1), x(0) does not exist. So the first value of Y cannot be calculated.

Comment: Yes Gelliant, I got it. This is is how I wanted the result. Thank you for the answer.